# How to add the age groups of age with the same values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

[image]

I need to unite the values and get the age with the three largest number of followers to make the graph the same as in the image. That is, I need to find the largest amount of each sex, add it up, and then bring in the three greatest ages.

For example: Male - 18-24 years : 30
Women - 18 -24 years: 50
Total = 18-24 years: 80

My Code

```
const value = {
  'U.45-54': 10,
  'U.35-44': 14,
  'U.25-34': 16,
  'U.55-64': 1,
  'U.13-17': 1,
  'M.65+': 3,
  'U.18-24': 8,
  'M.55-64': 8,
  'M.45-54': 27,
  'F.35-44': 287,
  'M.35-44': 102,
  'F.55-64': 37,
  'M.18-24': 17,
  'M.13-17': 1,
  'F.65+': 5,
  'F.25-34': 335,
  'F.45-54': 119,
  'M.25-34': 111,
  'F.18-24': 58,
};

const arr = Object.keys(value);


    const res = arr.reduce(
      (accum, item) => {
        const isFemale = item.startsWith('F');
        const isMale = item.startsWith('M');
        const ageRange = item.split('.')[1];
        if (isFemale) {
          if (!accum.Female[ageRange]) {
            accum['Female'] = {
              ...accum.Female,
              [ageRange]: value[item],
            };
          } else {
            accum['Female'] = {
              [ageRange]: accum.Female[ageRange] + value[item],
            };
          }
        } else if (isMale) {
          if (!accum.Male[ageRange]) {
            accum['Male'] = {
              ...accum.Male,
              [ageRange]: value[item],
            };
          } else {
            accum['Male'] = {
              [ageRange]: accum.Male[ageRange] + value[item],
            };
          }
        }

    return accum;
  },
  {
    Female: {},
    Male: {},
  },
);
```

return of console.log:

```
The output is:

const res = {
    Female: {
        '18-24' :58,
        '25-34' :335,
       ' 35-44' :287,
       ' 45-54' :119,
       ' 55-64' :37,
       ' 65+'   :5,
    },

    Male: {
        '13-17':1,
        '18-24':17,
        '25-34':111,
        '35-44':102,
        '45-54':27,
        '55-64':8,
        '65+'  :3

    }
  }
```

Comment: What is your question? What does not work as expected?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? Where did Male - 18-24 years : 30 Women - 18 -24 years: 50 Total = 18-24 years: 80 this come from?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const value = {'U.45-54': 10, 'U.35-44': 14, 'U.25-34': 16, 'U.55-64': 1, 'U.13-17': 1, 'M.65+': 3, 'U.18-24': 8, 'M.55-64': 8, 'M.45-54': 27, 'F.35-44': 287, 'M.35-44': 102, 'F.55-64': 37, 'M.18-24': 17, 'M.13-17': 1, 'F.65+': 5, 'F.25-34': 335, 'F.45-54': 119, 'M.25-34': 111, 'F.18-24': 58, };

const res = Object.keys(value).reduce((accum, item) => {
    const [ gender, age ] = item.split('.');
    const genderKey = (gender === 'F') ? 'Female' : 'Male';    
    
    accum[genderKey][age] = value[item];

    return accum;
}, { Female: {}, Male: {}, });

const getHighestKey = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((a, b) => obj[a] > obj[b] ? a : b);

const highestMale = getHighestKey(res['Male'])
const highestFemale = getHighestKey(res['Female'])

console.log(`Male: ${highestMale} ${res['Male'][highestMale]}`);
console.log(`Male: ${highestFemale} ${res['Female'][highestFemale]}`);
console.log(`Total: ${res['Male'][highestMale] + res['Female'][highestFemale]}`);
```